# Rename Excel Sheet with VBA Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I want to ask about rename the excel sheet, i want to rename the sheet with new name : older name + _v1.

So if my current sheet name is *test*, then I want the new name *test_v1*.

I only know the standard vba for rename excel sheet which is renaming excel sheet by the sheet content.

```
Sub Test()

Dim WS As Worksheet

For Each WS In Sheets
   WS.Name = WS.Range("A5")
Next WS
End Sub
```

Comment: `WS.Name = WS.Name & "_v1"`

Comment: @TimWilliams Can you add this as an answer

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This should do it:

```
WS.Name = WS.Name & "_v1"
```

Answer (score 26):

The "no frills" options are as follows:

```
ActiveSheet.Name = "New Name"
```

and

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Name = "New Name"
```

You can also check out recording macros and seeing what code it gives you, it's a great way to start learning some of the more vanilla functions.

Answer (score 5):

Suggest you add handling to test if any of the sheets to be renamed already exist:

```
Sub Test()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim strErr As String

On Error Resume Next
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
Set ws1 = Sheets(ws.Name & "_v1")
    If ws1 Is Nothing Then
        ws.Name = ws.Name & "_v1"
    Else
         strErr = strErr & ws.Name & "_v1" & vbNewLine
    End If
Set ws1 = Nothing
Next
On Error GoTo 0

If Len(strErr) > 0 Then MsgBox strErr, vbOKOnly, "these sheets already existed"

End Sub
```